# Evaluate $ I=\iint\limits_S yz^2\ dx\ dz\ \ \text{where}\ S\ \text{is the inner side of a cylinder}$

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

**Problem:**

> Evaluate $I$:
>   $$
> I=\iint\limits_S yz^2\ dx\ dz\ \ \text{where}\ S\ \text{is the inner side of a cylinder}\ x^2+y^2=r^2,\ y\leqslant 0,\ 0\leqslant z\leqslant r
> $$

**My attempt №1:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
&y\leqslant0\Rightarrow y=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2},\\
&\text{The normal that goes through the inner side of $S$ makes an acute angle with $Oy+$, therefore we get:}\\
&I=-\iint\limits_{D(x,z)}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}z^2\ dx\ dz=-\int\limits_0^r z^2\ dz\int\limits_{-r}^{r}\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ dx=-\frac{2r^3}{3}\int\limits_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\ dx
\end{aligned}
$$
And then I realized that something went wrong. I also tried a different approach.

**My attempt №2**
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\begin{cases}
x=u\cos v\\
y=u\sin v\\
z=u
\end{cases},\ r=r(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
r'_u=(\cos v, \sin v, 1)\\
r'_v=(-u\sin v, u\cos v, 0)
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\\
&\Rightarrow r'_u\times r'_v=(-u\cos v, -u\sin v, u)\\
&I=\iint\limits_{D(u,v)}\langle(0,yz^2,0),(u\cos v, -u\sin v, u)\rangle\ du\ dv=-\iint\limits_{D(u,v)} u^4\sin^2v\ du\ dv=\\
&=-\int\limits_0^r u^4\ du\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}\sin^2 v\ dv=-\frac{r^5}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\pi=-\frac{\pi r^5}{10}
\end{aligned}
$$
However, the correct answer is this:
$$I=-\frac{\pi r^5}{6}$$

Could someone explain what is wrong with my attempts?

Comment: your first attempt was correct, just go on integrating further and you will get the answer.

Comment: you mistakenly did the wrong transformation of variables, see that x and y lie on the circle of radius r only so the transformation would be $x=r\cos{v}, y=r\sin{v},z=u$ where $0 \le u \le r$, $ \pi \le v \le 2\pi $ as well as this a surface integral of a scalar function why are you using the dot product/inner product.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain one more thing? How do I know when to use $r'_u\times r'_v$ and when $r'_v\times r'_u$. For example, I don't really understand why I should use the former in my solution here.

Comment: but then the answer would be $+\frac{\pi r^5}{6}$, wouldn't it?

Comment: there are two cases,(i) where you do surface integrals of scalar functions like this, here you use only the norm... so no matter which one you use (ii) where you find surface integral of vector fields, there you choose $ r^{'}_{u}\times r^{'}_{v}\;$ or $\; r^{'}_{v}\times r^{'}_{u}$ as which one points along the normal to the surface you had in your original integral $\int\int{\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{S}}\;$, i.e. $d\mathbf{S}$

Comment: no, the answer would be $-\frac{\pi r^5}{6}$ only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The half-cylinder $C$ is parametrised by 
$$
{\bf r}(\theta,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)
$$ 
where $y\leq 0$ requires $\pi\leq\theta\leq 2\pi$ and the height range is $0\leq z\leq r$. The scalar field we are integrating over $C$ is given by 
$$
f(x,y,z)=yz^2
$$
We need to evaluate 
$$
I=\iint_D f({\bf r}(\theta,z))\|{\bf r}_{\theta}\times {\bf r}_z\|d\theta dz
$$
where $D=\{(\theta,z): \pi\leq\theta\leq 2\pi, 0\leq z\leq r\}$.

Well, ${\bf r}_{\theta}=(-r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta,0)$ and ${\bf r}_z=(0,0,1)$. Hence, ${\bf r}_{\theta}\times {\bf r}_z=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,0)$ which means that $\|{\bf r}_{\theta}\times {\bf r}_z\|=r$ and hence the infinitesimal area element is $dS = \|{\bf r}_{\theta}\times {\bf r}_z\|d\theta dz = rd\theta dz$, as intuition confirms it should be: $r d\theta$ is the sector length (or width) of the area element and $dz$ is the vertical height of the area element, so the area is $r d\theta\times dz$.

Putting all the pieces together, using that $y=r\sin\theta$ and $z$ is itself, we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
I 
&=&
\int_{\theta=\pi}^{2\pi}\int_{z=0}^{z=r} (r\sin\theta)(z^2)rd\theta dz\\
&=&
r^2\int_{\theta=\pi}^{2\pi}\sin\theta d\theta\int_{z=0}^{z=r}z^2dz\\
&=&
r^2\Big(-\cos\theta|_{\theta=\pi}^{2\pi}\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{3}z^3|_{z=0}^{z=r}\Big)\\
&=&
r^2\Big(-2\Big)\Big(\frac{1}{3}r^3\Big)\\
&=&
-\frac{2}{3}r^5
\end{eqnarray*}

I don't think the question is correctly formulated since $dxdz$ does not describe the infinitesimal area $dS$ of $C$. In the original coordinates $(x,y,z)$ the infinitesimal area element is given by 
$$
\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}dz = \sqrt{1+\Big(\frac{dy}{dx}\Big)^2}dxdz = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}dxdz = r d\theta dz
$$
where you use $y=-\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ then substitute in $x=r\cos\theta$ and $dx=-r\sin\theta d\theta$. Your attempt No 1. does integrate to $-\frac{\pi}{6}r^5$ but I don't believe this answer is the correct answer for the surface integral of $f(x,y,z)=yz^2$ over $C$. Your attempt No 2. is an attempt to integrate a vector field over $C$ when what you want is to do is integrate a scalar field over $C$, as I have done above. It would be helpful if you could double check that the statement of the problem is correct.